# What is wrong in sql

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, datetime-conversion

What is wrong in sql

```
CONCAT(title, ', from ', CONVERT(DATETIME,CONVERT(NVARCHAR,startdate,107)), ' to ', CONVERT(DATETIME,CONVERT(NVARCHAR,end_date,107)), ' (', duration , ')')
```

I want to change datetime to Sep 25, 2018 format

Comment: What database are you using?  What does your data look like?  What results are you getting?  What results do you want to get?

Comment: The convert with 107 implies SQL Server - but thats being converted back to a datetime, so I suspect the 'wrong' part here is that the formatting on the result is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT LEFT(DATENAME(MONTH, GETDATE()), 3) + ' ' + cast(datepart(dd, getdate()) as varchar) + ', ' + cast(datepart(yyyy, getdate()) as varchar)
```

or

```
select convert(nvarchar,getdate(),107)
```

Comment: `select convert(nvarchar,getdate(),107)` would achieve the same in a simpler manner, I don't believe the problem is the original conversion, but the conversion back to datetime he is doing after that.

Answer (score 0):

The question is somewhat unclear, I think your issue lies in that you are converting the date to an nvarchar using the 107 format which is correct for what you posted you wish to do. You then convert it back to a datetime, which reverts it back to the default settings for the date.

So I think you just need to simplify it to:

```
CONCAT(title, ', from ',CONVERT(NVARCHAR,startdate,107), ' to ',CONVERT(NVARCHAR,end_date,107), ' (', duration , ')')
```

Original:

```
select convert(datetime,convert(nvarchar,getdate(),107));
```

Returns (this is based on local settings, so for the SQL Server I used, it returns this):

```
2018-08-30 00:00:00.000
```

Less Conversion Code:

```
select convert(nvarchar,getdate(),107);
```

Returns:

```
Aug 30, 2018
```